# IAR: Genrate Source files using a pre-build and then add source files to project

Tags: iar

I'm using nanopb in my project and I'm generating C files from protocol buffer files. I want to run nanopb every time the build runs. I figure the way to do this is to use the pre build actions in IAR however, I don't know how to add the sources that are generated to the project so that it will compile the generated files.

Typically I manually add files to the project by specifically adding them to the workspace. Is there a way I can add generated sources after they have been generated in the the pre-build action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run pre-build once, to generate the source files. Then you can simply add those files to IAR project just like usual source files.

You can also add files manually. `.ewp` file is a XML file. Just add new `file` element:

```
<file>
   <name>$PROJ_DIR$\relative\path\to\file.c</name>
</file>
```

**Or**

Create file which where you will include all generated files:

```
// non-generated_file.c
#include "generated/file_a.c"
#include "generated/file_b.c"
```